# How to generate extent report for cucumber + testng framework

Tags: cucumber, testng, extentreports

How to generate extent report for cucumber +  testng framework in such a way that on each scenario failure I can get the screen shot captured, without repeating the code with every scenario in step definition file

I have setup the Testing framework using Cucumber+Testng. However, I need extent reporting but not sure how to achieve it through testNG runner class without actually repeating the code with every scenario of step definition. So the idea is to write code in one place just like using cucumber hooks which will run for each and every scenario.

```
I Have already tried the approach with TestNG listener with Extent report but with this the drawback is I have to write the code every time for each and every scenario. LIke below I have ITestListnerImpl.java, ExtentReportListner and YouTubeChannelValidationStepDef where for each scenario I have to repeat the loginfo and screencapture methods
```

Code: ItestListerner.java

```java
package com.testuatomation.Listeners;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;

public class ITestListenerImpl extends ExtentReportListener implements ITestListener {

    private static ExtentReports extent;

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        extent.flush();
        System.out.println("Execution completed on UAT env ......");                
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        extent = setUp();           
        System.out.println("Execution started on UAT env ......");          
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("FAILURE");          
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult arg0) {
        System.out.println("SKIP");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {
        System.out.println("STARTED");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("PASS-----");    
    }       

}
```

ExtentReportListener. java

```java
package com.testuatomation.Listeners;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.ExtentColor;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.MarkupHelper;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

public class ExtentReportListener {

    public static ExtentHtmlReporter report = null;
    public static ExtentReports extent = null;
    public static ExtentTest test = null;

    public static ExtentReports setUp() {
        String reportLocation = "./Reports/Extent_Report.html";
        report = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportLocation);        
        report.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Test Report");
        report.config().setReportName("Automation Test Report");
        report.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);       
        System.out.println("Extent Report location initialized . . .");
        report.start();

        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(report);      
        extent.setSystemInfo("Application", "Youtube");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Operating System", System.getProperty("os.name"));
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        System.out.println("System Info. set in Extent Report");        
        return extent;
    }

    public static void testStepHandle(String teststatus,WebDriver driver,ExtentTest extenttest,Throwable throwable) {
        switch (teststatus) {
        case "FAIL":        
            extenttest.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel("Test Case is Failed : ", ExtentColor.RED));           
            extenttest.error(throwable.fillInStackTrace());

            try {
                extenttest.addScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreenShot(driver));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            if (driver != null) {
                driver.quit();
            }       
        break;

        case "PASS":            
            extenttest.pass(MarkupHelper.createLabel("Test Case is Passed : ", ExtentColor.GREEN));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public static String captureScreenShot(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
        TakesScreenshot screen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File src = screen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String dest = "C:\\Users\\Prateek.Nehra\\workspace\\SeleniumCucumberBDDFramework\\screenshots\\" + getcurrentdateandtime() + ".png";
        File target = new File(dest);
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, target);
        return dest;
    }

    private static String getcurrentdateandtime() {
        String str = null;
        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS");
            Date date = new Date();
            str = dateFormat.format(date);
            str = str.replace(" ", "").replaceAll("/", "").replaceAll(":", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return str;
    }       
}
```

YoutubeChannelValidationsStepDef.java

```java
package com.testautomation.StepDef;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.GherkinKeyword;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Feature;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Scenario;
import com.testuatomation.Listeners.ExtentReportListener;
import com.testautomation.PageObjects.YoutubeChannelPage;
import com.testautomation.PageObjects.YoutubeResultPage;
import com.testautomation.PageObjects.YoutubeSearchPage;
import com.testautomation.Utility.BrowserUtility;
import com.testautomation.Utility.PropertiesFileReader;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class YoutubeChannelValidationsStepDef extends ExtentReportListener
{
    PropertiesFileReader obj= new PropertiesFileReader();
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^Open Chrome browser with URL$")
    public void open_Chrome_browser_with_URL() throws Throwable
    {
        ExtentTest logInfo=null;
        try {
            test = extent.createTest(Feature.class, "Youtube channel name validation");                         
            test=test.createNode(Scenario.class, "Youtube channel name validations");                       
            logInfo=test.createNode(new GherkinKeyword("Given"), "open_Chrome_browser_with_URL");
            Properties properties=obj.getProperty();        
            driver=BrowserUtility.OpenBrowser(driver, properties.getProperty("browser.name"), properties.getProperty("browser.baseURL"));

            logInfo.pass("Opened chrome browser and entered url");
            logInfo.addScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreenShot(driver));            

        } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
            testStepHandle("FAIL",driver,logInfo,e);            
        }       
    }

    @When("^Search selenium tutorial$")
    public void search_selenium_tutorial() throws Throwable 
    {
        ExtentTest logInfo=null;
        try {

            logInfo=test.createNode(new GherkinKeyword("When"), "search_selenium_tutorial");
            new YoutubeSearchPage(driver).NavigateToResultPage("selenium by bakkappa n");
            logInfo.pass("Searching selenium tutorial");
            logInfo.addScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreenShot(driver));

        } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
            testStepHandle("FAIL",driver,logInfo,e);            
        }


    }

    @When("^Search selenium tutorial \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void search_selenium_tutorial(String searchString) throws Throwable 
    {
        new YoutubeSearchPage(driver).NavigateToResultPage(searchString);
    }

    @When("^Click on channel name$")
    public void click_on_channel_name() throws Throwable 
    {
        ExtentTest logInfo=null;
        try {

            logInfo=test.createNode(new GherkinKeyword("When"), "click_on_channel_name");
            new YoutubeResultPage(driver).NavigateToChannel();
            logInfo.pass("Clicked on the channel name");
            logInfo.addScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreenShot(driver));

        } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
            testStepHandle("FAIL",driver,logInfo,e);            
        }


    }

    @Then("^Validate channel name$")
    public void validate_channel_name() throws Throwable
    {
        ExtentTest logInfo=null;
        try {                                   
            logInfo=test.createNode(new GherkinKeyword("Then"), "validate_channel_name");
            String expectedChannelName="1Selenium Java TestNG Tutorials - Bakkappa N - YouTube";
            String actualChannelName=new YoutubeChannelPage(driver).getTitle();
            Assert.assertEquals(actualChannelName, expectedChannelName,"Channel names are not matching");  //
            logInfo.pass("Validated channel title");
            logInfo.addScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreenShot(driver));
            System.out.println("closing browser");
            driver.quit();

        } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
            testStepHandle("FAIL",driver,logInfo,e);            
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: are you using info.cukes dependencies or io.cucumber ?

Comment: I have both the dependencies present. Will it make any difference here ?

Answer (score 0):

Your lofInfo is null, should be  something like this

```
    @Then("Open Chrome browser with URL")
    public void open_Chrome_browser_with_URL() {
        try {
            logInfo = test.createNode(new GherkinKeyword("Then"), "open_Chrome_browser_with_URL");

//YOUR CODE HERE

            logInfo.pass("Chrome opens URL");
        }
        catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {testStepHandle("FAIL", d, logInfo, e);
}
    }
```